# Angular 4 nested component with asp core 2.0

Tags: asp.net, angularjs-directive

I am new in asp core 2.0 with angular 4.
Can anyone help me to use component inside app.component.ts as I was using directive in angular 2 but in angular 4 there is no directive any more

helping code :

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

app.component.html

```
<div class='container-fluid'>
    <div class='row'>
        **<mycomponentname></mycomponentname>**
    </div>
</div>
```

this gets an error: Template parse errors:
'mycomponentname' is not a known element:
1. If 'mycomponentname' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you just need to create another Component.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'mycomponentname',
    templateUrl: './mycomponentname.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./mycomponentname.component.css']
})
export class MyComponent {
}
```

and simply import into app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

// If they in the same direction
// import { ClassName } from 'direction of TS file without .ts extension'
   import { MyComponent } from './mycomponent'; /// <<<----

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

Comment: Exactly what you said thanks, in visual studio template there is no app.module.ts . instead i add my component in app.module.shared.ts and it works